# HtmlAgilityPack remove node (thead) not working

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Want to remove a complete thead (including th's). Why this doesn't work?
I've tried other tags and nothing happens, result text is the same. like there were no changes.

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Hora</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Motivo</th>
         <th>Local</th>
         <th>Recetor</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
 </table>
```

c# code

```
doc.LoadHtml("<table><thead><th>Hora</th><th>Estado</th><th>Motivo</th><th>Local</th><th>Recetor</th></thead></table>");

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//thead").ToList();

foreach (var node in nodes) {
  node.Remove();
}

txtResults.Text=doc.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

`HtmlDocument.Text` property has very unclear description:

> The HtmlDocument Text. Careful if you modify it.

From observed behavior it looks like this property is not updated when you modify html document. So use `doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml` instead.

---

Update: From `ParsedText` property implementation it looks like `Text` supposed to hold original unmodified parsed text:

```
public string ParsedText
{
    get { return Text; }
}
```

But this is not even a read-only property - it's a public field that can be modified anytime by anyone. So I would not trust the `HtmlDocument.Text` as its description says.

Comment: Perfect. Document was not in fact updated. Thanks

Comment: Yes I've trusted, and result was not deleting as expected. OuterHtml holds updated string.